# sql server migration assistant for oracle to azure sql

Tags: sql-server, migration, oracle-11g

I am facing below error while syncing table from oracle to Azure SQL database using SSMA tool(A tool used to migrate data from oracle to azure SQL). Please suggest a solution.

> Errors: USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different Database.
>   Synchronization error: USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different Database

I am unable to identify the rectification of this error in SSMA. Would help lots to know the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

These two articles sum up the issue here:

http://www.heidisql.com/forum.php?t=17999

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384554/sync-oracle-database-with-sql-azure

Basically the SQL Azure service is not a usual fully fledged SQL installation, this Microsoft article outlines the details http://blogs.msdn.com/b/socaldevgal/archive/2011/05/29/getting-started-with-sql-azure-development.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the links but it was not helpful for me. I am trynig to migrate tables from oracle to azure SQL DW using SQL Server Migration Assistant  V6.0 tool. And I am able to connect to the db but unable to sync  the tables and schema after converting the schema as per Azure SQL .

Comment: The error you are getting still indicates that there are some things still not converted correctly though; in Azure db the USE statement for changing databases isn’t supported